# Textures w/ power of two dimensions in Cocos2d for iOS

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, textures

I've read about using textures w/ power-of-two dimensions in a number of places. **What are the best practices w/ texture dimensions when using Cocos2d?**

Say I have `MyTexture.png` and the dimensions are `100x100`. Currently I just use the texture as-is and ignore the non power-of-two dimensions. Perhaps there's a benefit from adjusting the texture size to `128x128` and then setting the `contentSize` to `100x100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find some info about this. This is a discussion about POT and NPOT textures and possible bugs that could make some memory issues on you app, check this link

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/31092

besides that i think that there is no big difference from POT or NPOT textures, but i'm not an expert on this topic.

Comment: There is if you look at it from the GPU perspective. In general, POT textures render faster (if NPOT textures render at all), so you usually want to use POT textures only.